# Convert Rows into Cols

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have the following table call fc_summary:

```
CALMONTH   COMP_CODE    FC10    FC20    FC30
201901     C001         550      45     100
201901     C002         50       450    10
201901     C003         150      250    120
201901     C004         520      410    10
201901     C005         30       40     105
```

From it I would like to create my_summary table like

```
CALMONTH   CODE     AMOUNT
201901     FC10     1300
201901     FC20     1195
201901     FC30     345
```

I tried to achieve this using PIVOT but could not figure it

Comment: You need `unpivot`. There are plenty of similiar questions already answered on SO. Once you unpivot data you need only `sum` with `group by calmonth, code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query

```
with t(CALMONTH, COMP_CODE, FC10, FC20, FC30) as
(
 select 201901,'C001',550,45,100  from dual union all
 select 201901,'C002',50,450,10   from dual union all
 select 201901,'C003',150,250,120 from dual union all
 select 201901,'C004',520,410,10  from dual union all
 select 201901,'C005',30,40,105   from dual
)
select CALMONTH, FC as CODE, SUM(VALUE) as VALUE
  from t
 unpivot 
 (
  VALUE for FC in (FC10,FC20,FC30)
 )  
 group by CALMONTH, FC
 order by FC;

CALMONTH    CODE    VALUE
201901      FC10    1300
201901      FC20    1195
201901      FC30    345
```

to unpivot your data